# Methods query in ruby on rails - undefined method `read' for 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, methods, message

As part of learning ruby/rails, I'm trying to implement http://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages into my application from scratch, instead of just installing the plugin. (I know, causing myself trouble but it's a good learning experience.)

I created the model, and the associations seem ok and I can create new messages fine and they show up in the recipients mailbox. But if I click to view one message (calls the show method in the message controller) it trips up on looking for a method called 'read' eg.

```
undefined method `read' for #<Class:0xb6f9ef78>
```

Where should I put the 'read' method. In private_messages_extensions.rb (the plugin source) it has:

```
  module ClassMethods
    # Ensures the passed user is either the sender or the recipient then returns the message.
    # If the reader is the recipient and the message has yet not been read, it marks the read_at timestamp.
    def read(id, reader)
      message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", reader, reader])
      if message.read_at.nil? && reader == message.recipient
        message.read_at = Time.now
        message.save!
      end
      message
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # Returns true or false value based on whether the a message has been read by it's recipient.
    def read?
      self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end
```

What is the relationship between Class methods and Instance methods in relation to inserting directly into my own messages controller & model? I thought I inserted

```
def read(id, reader)
...
end
```

into the model, but the read? method in the instance methods section of the plugin code is confusing me and I continue to get the error on viewing a message.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassMethods / InstanceMethods is standard Ruby technique that is based on this code:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
  base.include InstanceMethods
end
```

which you will (roughly) find in the original code. By the way there is ActiveSupport::Concern that can simplify the code above (take a look into the documentation for more info)

So whenever the module is included in class then all methods in ClassMethods module will became *class* methods of the target class and all methods in InstanceMethods will become instance methods of target class.

So your `read` method is class method, which has to be called as:

```
m = MyModel.new
m.read?          # => ok, it is an instance method
MyModel.read     # => ok, it is a class method
m.read           # => oops, WRONG! FAILURE! 
                 # You are calling class method through object
```

Meta-programming rules!

If you rewrite the code without meta thing, you should write it as:

```
class MyModel
  def self.read
  end

  def read?
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the plug-in but based on the standards from other plug-ins, I think you need something like this:

```
def self.read(id, reader)
  ...
end
```

This will make it a class method, accessible by calling `User.read`.

(I am assuming this because of the `module ClassMethods` block)